# Convert this picture to Latex format

Tags: cv, awesome-cv

Attached is what I want to print in LaTeX. This is the [link to the template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv/dfnvtnhzhhbm). The template does not have this section, I want to add this.

Any experts in LaTeX, please help this would be very helpful[image]

Comment: The `awsome-cv` class provides a `\cvsection{...}` command to format the "About Me" and the line. If you're having trouble with something else, please create a compilable minimal document that shows what you have tried.

Comment: hey alan, I tried doing this and I am still confused. do you mind hopping on a call with me?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example that should at least give you something to start with. I placed a section "About Me" using `\cvsection`, and I placed a `cvskills` list in this section. To list the skills from your example, I defined an inline list environment `skillslist` with `enumitem`'s commands. The output is fairly similar to the image you linked.

[image]

```
\documentclass{awesome-cv}
\newlist{skillslist}{itemize*}{1}
\setlist[skillslist]{
    label=,
    afterlabel=,
    itemjoin=\(\ \cdot\ \),
}
\begin{document}
\cvsection{About Me}
\begin{cvskills}
    \cvskill{Programming}{\begin{skillslist}
        \item C++/C
        \item Python
        \item NodeJS
        \item Bash
    \end{skillslist}}
    \cvskill{Analytics}{\begin{skillslist}
        \item IPython
        \item SQL
        \item Tableau
        \item Excel/VBA
        \item R
    \end{skillslist}}
    \cvskill{Web/Media}{\begin{skillslist}
        \item Express
        \item Flask
        \item HTML/CSS/Javascript
        \item Photoshop
        \item Premiere Pro
    \end{skillslist}}
\end{cvskills}
\end{document}
```

There is more information about `awesome-cv`
[on GitHub](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV), with useful examples.